# MySQL FIND_IN_SET With Array String

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a field in a table I am querying that looks similar to this:

```
Name          Phone          Category_IDS          Category_Labels
Sample        1111111111     ["1"]                 ["foo", "bar"]
```

I am trying to use the FIND_IN_SET function to find all rows that contain one of the values listed in the comma separated list. Something like this returns nothing:

```
SELECT * FROM sampletable WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1', category_ids) <> 0
```

It does work if I do this:

```
SELECT * FROM factual_usplaces WHERE FIND_IN_SET('["1"]', category_ids) <> 0
```

But of course that limits to searches to rows where the category_ids or labels only contains a single value in the comma separated list. So ["1"] would be found but ["1", "2"] would not.

Is there a way to remove the brackets and quotations from the string on the fly in the query?

Comment: Very strange data in table. And why are they wrapped in [...]? I would suggest you to read an article about the database normalizing.

Comment: The table is actually not originated by me, its a company called Factual that is quite widely known and used. Its strange that they wrap in brackets to me too...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If data is stored exactly how you showed it then you can use [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) to strip double quotes and brackets before feeding `category_ids` to `FIND_IN_SET()`.

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1 
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1, REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                          REPLACE(category_ids, '"', ''), 
                        '[', ''), 
                      ']','')) > 0
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b269a/1)**

---

Now if you will use it a lot then you may consider to create a user defined function to simplify your code

```
CREATE FUNCTION UNQOUTE_LIST(_list VARCHAR(512)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(512)
RETURN 
REPLACE(
  REPLACE(
    REPLACE(_list, '"', ''), 
  '[', ''), 
']','');
```

And use it

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1 
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1, UNQOUTE_LIST(category_ids)) > 0
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1c39/1)**

Comment: Replace was the key here. So you can't replace multiple characters with one replace function I assume?

Comment: No, unfortunately you can't.

Comment: This is not working when I'm searching on a string so I'm posting a new answer which works for me.

Answer (score 1):

try below sql query with like operator

SELECT * FROM factual_usplaces WHERE category_ids LIKE '%1,2%'

Hope This help you

Comment: Like won't work. I need to use the FIND_IN_SET function otherwise it will cause a load of other problems.

Comment: SELECT * FROM factual_usplaces WHERE (
FIND_IN_SET( '1', category_ids  )
)
OR (
FIND_IN_SET( '2', category_ids )
)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1 
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET("bar", REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(`Category_Labels`, '\"', ''), '[', ''), ']',''))
```

This is working for me