# MYSQL Find In Set with Array Data

Tags: mysql, json

I have a Database that looks like this (unfortunately cannot be changed)

```
patients (table)
name    |   companies
-----------------------
Form 1  |     [8,3]
Form 2  |     [8]
```

I want to select every form with an assignment of 8 so I tried this:

`SELECT * FROM patients WHERE FIND_IN_SET(patients, 8)`

But it's not working, I tried another test in a sample database and if the `[` and `]` is removed it works just fine, unfortunately the `[` and `]` cannot be removed in the live database (this data is stringified from JSON)

Comment: I think you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448897/mysql-query-where-column-is-in-json-array#37838101  but for this you need mysql 5.7+ version. Will not work in mysqk 5.6 or minor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [REPLACE()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php) to strip `[` and `]` brackets before using companies in `FIND_IN_SET`.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM patients 
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(8, REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                          companies, 
                        '[', ''), 
                      ']',''))
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/485ae/2)

Please refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710921/mysql-find-in-set-with-array-string)  for the same scenario.

Comment: Does this modify the values in the db?

Comment: @Jordash No, it should not.