# MYSQL - using array in WHERE IN clause

Tags: mysql, where-in, json-arrayagg

Having a json array column in a table e.g. ["A1", "A2", "B1"]. I want to reference that array in WHERE IN clause. I could not evaluate the json array to ... WHERE tbl2.refID IN ("A1", "A2", "B1").

`SET @ref = replace(replace('["A1", "A2", "BI"]','[', ''), ']', ''); SELECT @ref;`
returns "A1", "A2", "B1" as I want it but not working in ... WHERE tbl2.refID IN (@ref)

So how can I evaluate array to be used as "WHERE IN" values?

Table 1

| id | array of ids | other cols |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ["A1", "A2", "B1"] |  |

Table 2

| id | refID | col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | [ ] |
| 2 | A2 | [ ] |

Using elements of table1.col2 I want to select and group col3 from table2.

Wished I could illustrate it better!

I have tried to evaluate the array column passed to WHERE IN () but not returning any value.
The evaluation is broken somehow.

`WHERE tbl2.refID IN (replace(replace('["A1", "A2", "B1"]','[', ''), ']', ''));` not evaluating

Comment: find_In_set() maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45767566/mysql-find-in-set-with-array-data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could search in the JSON if the value exists with `JSON_CONTAINS`

[Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b47efce5b7b84d3b6d4da31b8e33c3cd)

Beware, `JSON_CONTAINS` needs a valid JSON on the two parameters, so `JSON_CONTAINS('["A1"]', 'A1')` we be invalid as `A1` is not a valid JSON string representation.

---

For the where, you can simply do

```sql
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS('["A1", "A2", "BI"]', JSON_QUOTE(tbl2.refID))
```

It will add quotes around strings and test it against your array.

Comment: Thank you @Joel, works as expected, even in expanded query where I need it